# Pressing enter on submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, events, submit

Why when i press enter it doesn't run the `code`, cause i put the code that should run in the `if statement`.
When i press `enter` it `console log` it not run it properly.

```
document.getElementById('city-location').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const LOCATION = document.getElementById('city-location').value
    if(e.target.which == 13 || e.target.keyCode == 13) {
        weatherApi.changeLocation(LOCATION);
        storage.setStorage(LOCATION);
        getWeatherApi();
    } else {
        console.log('Wrong key pressed');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Here is the markup:

```
<form id="weather-modal-form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city-location">
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `submit` event for enter buttons.

```js
document.getElementById('weather-modal-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("work's");
})
```

```html
<form id="weather-modal-form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city-location">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to submit the form when i press enter directly on the input. i don't want any buttons.

Comment: @Grecdev update my snippet check out.Work's without any button's.

Comment: Ok, but now when i press the `enter` key it works perfectly fine, but it runs the `else statement` code. Why so ?

Comment: Becouse your listener is set on the form and not in the input field. Your else statement controls the key pressed, and the form doesn't have this information: the e.target.which and e.target.keyCode are `undefined`) so the if is `false`.
Just put your code before the `console.log("work's")`, it shoud work.